# How to click a checkbox by text of another table value

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, junit

I have a page with a table which has the following html

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <div>
              <input /> <----what I want to click
          </div>
       </td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td>
          <div>
              <a>
                 <span>text here</span> <-----how i find correct table row
              </a>
          </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem is "text here" is the only piece of information I will have for locating the correct checkbox to click.

What I have tried is

```
this.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='" + texthere + "']/parent::tr/following-sibling::td/div/input")).click();
```

how ever it cant find the element.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
* first find the child node you want
* then find the first ancestor of the desired element type (in your case "tr")
* then get the first input element below this tr

```
String xpathExpression = "//tbody//span[contains(., 'text here')]/ancestor::tr[1]//input";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below xpath:-

```
this.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//tbody//td[text()='"+texthere+"']/preceding-sibling::td//input")).click();
```

in above xpath, we are finding **td** tag which contains **text here** and with reference to this tag we are finding its preceding sibling **td** such that it contains input tag